# Search for a pattern in text file using c#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, text-files

I have multiple text files.I need value `'UA-8798837-1'` (without the qoutes) from the code below.
So steps will be-:

1. open the text file abc.txt .
2. search for a pattern starting from `"_gaq.push".`
3. If pattern matches I will skip a few characters `"(['_setAccount', ".`
4. select the key `'UA-8798837-1'`(without quotes).
5. Save this key value in a variable called "key".

Text file's code -:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-8798837-1']);
<script>
```

So basically I need to search for a pattern and if that is found I need to skip a few characters to select a code which is after the character " ' " and copy this value till the character " ' " is found again.
Selection start at character `" ' "`  `'UA-8798837-1'` and ends at character `" ' "` value is UA-8798837-1.
Please tell me how to do it .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that all Google Analytics codes start with "UA-". If this is true, you might be able to simplify your search to look for that text and grab everything up until a `'` or `"` character.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple regex:

`/\[\'_setAccount\', \'(.+)\'/`

You can see what the matched groups will look like [here.](http://rubular.com/r/KFVfpd9LjP)

And in case you haven't worked with regex in C# before, [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) is a good place to get started. Since you want to work with multiple matches, [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches) is probably even more relevant.

Comment: But then how to select that value UA-8798837-1 c# code please.

Comment: I'm not going to write your program for you. I already provided links that should help you out. If you have specific questions about problems you're having then come back with them, I doubt that you'll find anyone here willing to do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
(?<=_gaq\.push\(\['_setAccount',\s')(.*)(?=')
```

If that will always be the case, you can use that regex to match the key that you are looking for
.

But I will not give you the code for getting it in C# code, Please let me know what you tried. Thanks.

Hope it helps.